# Update request (PUT) timeout on Sequelize with Axios

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, axios, sequelize.js

I have this Axios function, which calls an API on Express with Sequelize and MariaDB.

```
 export async function updateUser(values) {
        const TOKEN = 'Bearer ' + getToken();
    let axiosConfig = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        'Authorization': TOKEN
}
};

 await axios.put('https://myapi.com/users', values, axiosConfig)
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
       console.log(res.data)
      } else {
        const error = new Error(res.error);
        throw error;
      }     

})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
})
  }
```

On the Backend server we have this:

```
 var express = require('express');
    const User = require('./model/User');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    const UserController = require('./components/userController');
    const verifyToken = require("./middle/verifyToken");
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    var cors = require('cors');




    var app = express();
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    app.use(cookieParser());

    //Ruta inicial (Backend)
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile('index.html');
    });

    app.use((req, res, next) => {
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
      res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
      next();
    });

    app.listen(4000, '0.0.0.0');

app.put('/actualitzar/',verifyToken,Accidents_basicController.update);


app.put('/users/actualitzar',UserController.update);
    app.get('/users',verifyToken,UserController.list);
```

I have the same request structure reproduced on both sequelize controllers, and one PUT request is 200 OK, and the other one times out on every call. This is the Sequelize controller for the update requests.

```
controllers.update = async (req, res) => {

  const data = await User.update({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, *),


  },{
    where: { id: req.body.id}
  })


  .then( function (data){
    return data;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    return error;
  })

  res.json({ success:true, data: data, message: "Updated successful"});

}
```

Does somebody see the problem?

Answer (score 0):

OKay, I've found the solution. The request sent to the backend didn't have a password change, and that returned a try from bcrypt to crypt an empty string. I solved it by handling if req.body.password is undefined.

Cheers!